# is it possible to get handles of all chars in a stage?

Tags: javascript, anychart

I wish to get handles of all the charts in a stage in order to modify background settings.

I noticed there is a `stage.forEachChild(function(element) { … })` method that allows you to fire up a function for each stage element.

For example:

```
stage.forEachChild(function(element) {
  alert(element.id());
});
```

The problem is that "element" type is `anychart.graphics.vector.Element`; instead I need a `anychart.core.Chart` object in order to call the `background()` method. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, is a GraphicsJS entity and it returns its graphic vector elements as children. It doesn't control charts. You can store all chart in an object or array and iterate them, or apply a unique ID to every chart and get access to them at any moment by `anychart.getChartById('CHART_ID');`. For details, check the sample by the link in a comment below.